# Detect iframe links inside a webview in Xamarin forms Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uiwebview, android-webview

I have a webview in the App. It initially opens a webpage in an iframe, which in turn when clicked it opens another webpage.

Webpage 1: com.test1.page1
WebPage 2: com.test2.page2

Once I navigate to webpage1, none of the navigating/navigated events are fired in my webview.

I successfully navigate to webPage2. But the URL of the webview is com.test2.page2

How do I detect/know that I navigated to Webpage 2 when the URL of the webview remains the same and navigated events in webview do not fire? How to detect iframe is being clicked inside the webview?

The webpage being hosted in an iframe is in ReactJS